# Struts2 Result type http header 500 does not trigger onErrorTopics in sj:autocompleter

Tags: jquery, error-handling, struts2, struts2-jquery

We have a Struts2 application using Struts2-jQuery framework for Ajax operations. While using the Autocompleter (sj:autocompleter) tag in Struts2-jQuery as follows, it makes an ajax request to the Struts2 Action jsonlanguages.

```
<s:url var="remoteurl" action="jsonlanguages"/>
<sj:autocompleter
    id="languages"
    href="%{remoteurl}"
    delay="50"
    loadMinimumCount="2"
/>
```

We have defined a result type ERROR for this action as follows, to trigger an Internal Server error instead of it getting completed as a successful ajax request.

```
<result name="ERROR" type="httpheader">
  <param name="status">500</param>
  <param name="headers.a">a custom header value</param>
  <param name="headers.b">another custom header value</param>
</result>
```

***Issue***: Now this approach triggers the `"onErrorTopics"` in all other Struts2-jQuery tags like `sj:select` ..etc, but it does not seem to be triggering the same in an `sj:autocompleter`. Has anybody faced this issue ? If so, what is the best way to handle exceptions that happen during an ajax request from an autocompleter ?

Answer (score 1):

I think it will not be possible to do exception handling at view until you yourself check for the validity of json returned.

BTW autocompleter do not return any result but a json object.

You can validate json returned by action in javascript or jquery.